# Whether $X_i's$ are dense

Tags: real-analysis

> Pick Out the Dense sets:
>
> a) $X_1=\Big\{A \in M_2(\Bbb{R}): \text{both eigenvalues of A are real}\Big\}$
>
> b) The subset $X_2$ of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support in $\Bbb{R}$ in the space of bounded real-valued continuous functions on $\Bbb{R}$

**My Try for $X_1$**:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in X_1$. Then $\rho_A(x)=x^2-(a+d)x+(ad-bc)$. Now eigenvalues of $A$ are real means $$x=\frac{(a+d) \pm \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc} }{2} \in \Bbb{R}$$

That means, $(a-d)^2+4bc \geq 0$

Therefore $X_1$ can be written as $$X_1=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\Bbb{R}):(a-d)^2+4bc \geq 0\Bigg\} $$

Now, consider $f:M_2(\Bbb{R}) \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ defined by $$f\Bigg(\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\Bigg)=(a-d)^2+4bc$$ Then $f$ is continuous and $[0,\infty)$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$, so its inverse image $X_1$ is closed in $M_2(\Bbb{R})$. Hence
$$\overline{X_1}=X_1\subset M_2(\Bbb{R}) $$ and so it is not dense.

Am I right? I have no idea about b)

Any help must be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct.
The example from b) is also not dense. Just take the constant function $1$. The open ball $B_1(1)$ has no function with compact support, since$$f\in B_1(1)\implies(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f(x)\in(0,2)\implies(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f(x)\neq0.$$

Comment: Thank you sir!(sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @LDM You know what they say: better late than never! I'm glad I could help.